# Php session not creating correctly

Tags: php, session

I'm new to PHP and havn't worked with sessions before, I have read up on it a bit and understand what they do and how i should be able to use them.

When I create my session however, it seems to create the session fine (code gets run and if I look into cookies I can see entries from my website)
I can also set $_SESSION values on the same page, but as soon as I enter a different page, the session is reset it seems.

Here's my code:

```
$sessionid = md5(uniqid(microtime()) . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
ini_set('session.auto_start', 1);
ini_set('session.lifetime', 2678400);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private_no_expire');
session_start($sessionid);

// Also tested that setting these doesn't give an error either
$_SESSION['Username'] = //Code to get username
$_SESSION['UserID'] = // Code to get userID

echo "<script language='Javascript'>";
echo "window.location='" . $forwardpage . "';";
echo '</script>';
exit();
```

Any help would be appereciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you load the script a new session id is created and sent to the client.
Skip the $sessionid variable and php will generate a sessionid for you and it will work.

So, use session_start() without $sessionid

Comment: Well that's how I did it at first, that's when it didn't work so I figured maybe if I create my own ID, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Normally the default settings for php sessions works good. Have you tried removing the ini_set() variables and tried with only a simple session_start() in the top?

Comment: Just to add to this, if you want to regenerate the session ID like you are doing above, use session_regenerate_id(); after starting the session to regenerate the ID and keep your session intact.